# How to remove "Select all" options from Django model admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin

Django model admin allows to select all the objects in a page to take certain actions ('Delete selected' being one of them). After selecting all the model objects in a User model page, it gives an option to "Select all xxxx users" (xxxx being a number) as shown in the image.

[image: Image showing 'select all' option]

This allows the admin to select all the users and when exported to CSV, such a huge data size causes Gateway Timeout issue. We only want the admin to select the objects in a single page and not all of it in one go. Any help regarding this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't click the `Select all XXX users` the action will be only performed on the ticked users (50) in your screenshot.

Comment: Yes. But this panel is used to export some data from the admin panel. And the 'Select All' option allows the admins to select all the records across pages. We can't have that option available and let everyone know not to use that. We don't have an option other than to remove 'select all' from there.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve. Your goal is to select some data across multiple pages?

Answer (score 0):

The template responsible for showing that bit in the admin panel is `admin/actions.html`. You can override the template for your model and remove that link from it.

The default template has a block like this:

```
{% if actions_selection_counter %}
    <span class="action-counter" data-actions-icnt="{{ cl.result_list|length }}">{{ selection_note }}</span>
    {% if cl.result_count != cl.result_list|length %}
    <span class="all hidden">{{ selection_note_all }}</span>
    <span class="question hidden">
        <a href="#" title="{% translate "Click here to select the objects across all pages" %}">{% blocktranslate with cl.result_count as total_count %}Select all {{ total_count }} {{ module_name }}{% endblocktranslate %}</a>
    </span>
    <span class="clear hidden"><a href="#">{% translate "Clear selection" %}</a></span>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

You want to override this template and remove the two spans in there that are links. In order to override the template for only one model, you should create this folder structure in your templates directory: `admin/<app_name>/<model_name>/`.

So to put it all together, assuming the app name is `accounts` and the model name is `User`, write this in `templates/admin/accounts/user/actions.html`:

```
{% extends "admin/actions.html" %}

{% load i18n %}

{% block actions-counter %}
{% if actions_selection_counter %}
    <span class="action-counter" data-actions-icnt="{{ cl.result_list|length }}">{{ selection_note }}</span>
    {% if cl.result_count != cl.result_list|length %}
    <span class="all hidden">{{ selection_note_all }}</span>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

More info on overriding templates: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates